# How to handle touch up event in GridView's child views

Tags: android, gridview

Application have a GridView with a images. When user press image - looped sound start playing. When user releases image - sound must stop playing.

I cannot find the way to handle release event.

Answer (score 0):

write touch event in getview method of adapter class. it will work.

Comment: at bottom return Boolean value as false.

Comment: MotionEvent.ACTION_UP never fires for child views. IFAIK AbsListView eates these events.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent e) {
switch(e.getAction()){

    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        //the user put his finger down on screen
    break;

    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
        //the user is moving with his finger down
    break;

    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        //the users finger is off the screen
    break;

    }
}
```